# Smarty: Why regex_replace with not working when use class in tag?

Tags: regex, smarty, smarty3

I am using smarty 3. I have tried this code:

```
{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":"<div class="xyz">anything</div>"}
```

and it returned the following error:

> HTTP ERROR 500

If I remove the `class="xyz"` inside the div tag and use the following code:

```
{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":"<div>anything</div>"}
```

it is working fine.

Comment: Use single quotes, `'<div class="xyz">anything</div>'`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, thank for guiding me. Works. Could you explain a bit how about it? {$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":'"><div class="xyz">anything</div>'} When adding replace with "> its not working.

Comment: Probably, that breaks something.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange.

Comment: So, how we can use "> ?

Comment: `{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":'"><div class="xyz">anything</div>'}` must work. If it does not, the issue is out there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181369/discussion-between-smaller-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you almost provided the answer to your question by yourself.

In smarty you've got your variable `$var` and you are using the smarty variable modifier [regex_replace](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) to do a regular expression search and replace on this variable.

The smarty variable modifier [regex_replace](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) requires two parameters:

[image]

Both parameters are of type `string`. The parameters in a smarty variable modifier are separated by a colon.

In your first code example

```
{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":"<div class="xyz">anything</div>"}
```

your first parameter is `"/something/"`, but the second one is broken because you don't escape the quotation marks!

In your second code example

```
{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":"<div>anything</div>"}
```

you removed the class attribute on your div, so you do not have the problem with escaping the quotation marks any more. That's why your second code example is working.

With that in mind, you can now correct your first code example by escaping the quotation marks

```
{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":"<div class=\"xyz\">anything</div>"}
```

or you can use single quotes, like suggested in comments:

```
{$ver|regex_replace:"/something/":"<div class='xyz'>anything</div>"}
```

Personally I prefer to use single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I also prefer single quotes now to prevent using multiple backslashes.